# Vector within an object going from populated to unpopulated after an overloaded operator call

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding a c++ assignment I'm doing but I'm hesitant to post the code because I'm worried about plagiarism charges...'

I have a class called `SparseMatrix` which has within it a few protected fields and a pointer to a vector of `SparseRow` objects. For the assignment we have to write a few overloaded operators. Cout, multiplication, addition and transpose.

The first one I have working is multiplication and the call looks like this

```
resultant = (*tempOne) * (*tempTwo);
```

The method returns the correct sparse matrix but `tempTwo`'s vector of `sparserows` goes from populated to unpopulated. All other information about `tempTwo` is retained. Only it's vector of `sparserows` is lost.

I know I'm asking a lot by not posting code, but does anyone have any idea what could cause this? I'm pulling my hair out over this and my prof. has a "no helping with debugging" rule.

Comment: "no helping with debugging rule" what? Do you mean the professor doesn't allow you to debug your program? That is just nuts. Do not listen to your professor on this!!!! Debug your program!!! Debugging is one of the if not the **most important** tools a developer has. He can't know if you debug your program or not. Debug your program!!

Comment: No, the "no helping with debugging" rule is that neither him nor the TA's will help with debugging. We can debug our programs.

Comment: Without any code my educated guess is that you don't manage the resources properly. Check the rule of 3/5. And strongly consider the rule of 0

Comment: I've been using my IDE's debugger and it's how I verified that the vector of sparserows is populated within the overloaded method call and then unpopulated directly after.

Comment: I just can't figure out how I would lose JUST the vector out of the object and all its other information is still there. Only operations I perform on the vector while in the overloaded method are getter calls.

Comment: Post a [mcve] (i.e. an example of your problem stripped of all actual relevant assignment variable names and the like.)

Comment: I'l check those rules out, thanks bolov